# Cannot see distinction between Decorator and Adapter

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, design-patterns

I know this two desing patterns, and how to implement them ( Adapter's Object and Class implementation ), but I cannot see clear distinction when to use each one.

For example in AS3 if I want to wrap a MovieClip class and add to it a button functionallity, should I use Adapter or Decorator desing pattern?

Comment: if you want to just add some additional functionality , use Decorator

Answer (score 1):

In implementation of both patterns the new object usually "wraps" the original object, so confusing them is entirely understandable.

But they have much different purposes.

In the Adapter pattern, you have the correct functionality in the original object, but need to use a different interface.

In the Decorator pattern, you want to use the original interface, but also to add functionality.

In your example of adding Button capability to a `MovieClip`, it's likely that what you want is a Decorator.

Comment: I can't really say much on the details, as I don't really know the AS3 classes involved.

Comment: This is pretty good answer, I just wonder how can I wrap MovieClip with Button functionallity, and still be coding to MovieClip interface.  
 For me it makes more sense, if I do : var button:IButton = new Button( mySkin ); // Button is Adapter than var button:MovieClip = new ButtonDecorator( mySkin );